# Python function to calculate discount

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

New to python. I am having trouble trying to make a loop to calculate discount for a lemonade stand, the example am working on is simple

lemonade 8oz = 1.20  #no discount

lemonade 12oz = 1.75 # for 4 and less cups

lemonade 12oz = 1.35 discount for every 5 cups, and less then 5 the discount does not apply. example if a customer buys 8 large cups 5 will be discounted and the 3 won't be.

Any help on how to make a function and variable for this problem. I know it is basic but am new to python.

Comment: `8 % 5 = 3` so you have cups without discount. `(8 // 5) * 5 = 5` so you have cups with discount. The same for 12 large cups - `12 % 5 = 2` without discount, `(12 // 5) * 5 = 10` with discount. Or if you have `12 % 5 = 2` without discount then you have `12 - 2 = 10` with discount.

Comment: Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
def discount(size, count):
    price_8oz = 1.20
    price_12oz = 1.75
    price_12oz_discount = 1.35

    if size == 8:
        return price_8oz * count
    elif size == 12:
        if count <= 4:
            return price_12oz * count
        elif count > 4:

            # divmod() divides one number by another and returns both the number of times
            #     the second number fits into the first, but also the remainder.
            # Here we calculate how many times five goes into the customer order 
            #     and how many extra cups are left over.
            fivecount, remainder = divmod(count, 5)
            return price_12oz_discount * fivecount * 5 + 1.75 * remainder

# Here we test the code to make sure that it works across several iterations of five counts
#    with 12 ounce cups.

for count in range(2, 12):
    print('count:', count, 'cost:', discount(12, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below and the associated comments.

```
#Lemonade prices variables
price_8oz = 1.2
price_12oz_without_discount = 1.75
price_12oz_discount = 1.35

#Function to calculate price
def price(no_8oz, no_12oz):

    #Total price of 8 oz is price multiplied by no of 8oz cups
    total_price_8oz = price_8oz*no_8oz

    #Number of 12oz without discount is the remainder after dividing by 5
    num_12oz_cups_without_discount = no_12oz%5

    #Number of 12oz with discount is total cups minus number of 12oz cups without discount
    num_12oz_cups_with_discount = no_12oz - num_12oz_cups_without_discount

    #Total price for 12oz cups
    total_price_12oz = num_12oz_cups_without_discount*price_12oz_without_discount + num_12oz_cups_with_discount*price_12oz_discount

    #Total price for all lemonades
    total_price = total_price_8oz + total_price_12oz

    return total_price

print(price(5, 5))
# 5*1.2 + 5*1.35 = 12.75
print(price(5, 4))
# 5*1.2 + 4*1.75 = 13.0
print(price(5, 14))
# 5*1.2 + 10*1.35 + 4*1.75 = 26.5
```

Comment: Thank you Devesh and Furas.